# Display child count after each page in book navigation

Tags: nodes

I'm building a hierarchical site. and I'm using the Book module. The desired output for each listed node in the book navigation is "Page 1 (node count) (last comment date)."

[The question](http://drupal.org/node/55731) was asked on Drupal.org back in 2006, and it got no answer. My client has strict requirements to display custom data beside each node (e.g. number of comments, date of most recent comment). If I can start with the node count, I'm one step closer.

[Vocabulary Index](http://drupal.org/project/vocabindex) includes node count but this is based on taxonomy.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal, AlxVallejo! :) Before I attempt to assist you, I would ask that you make the question more clear, more concise, and make the title better reflect the text.

Comment: I don't quite understand the node count requirement. Should each page list the total node count of the current book, or the number of children of the current page, or something else?

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. I'd like to count the number of children. I'm still tossed between using the Book module and using Views to build a hierarchical list. If I use Views, I'd filter by taxonomy term and then count the nodes of that taxonomy term.